# Excel formula to check if the character before a specific character is a number or not

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to pull a number within ()'s in the text of a cell. I am using this formula.

```
=MID(LEFT(A3,FIND(")",A3)-1),FIND("(",A3)+1,LEN(A3))
```

And it works perfectly except on a few cells. Some of the cells might look like this.

```
random text (09-12)
random Text Here (comment) more text (2018)
random text (2008)
random Text Here (comment) more text (04-08) more text here
```

I need to specifically only pull the number from within the parenthesis IF what is in the parenthesis is a number. Any help is appreciated.

To be clear, in the cell there will be text, followed by () with a date range in it. Sometimes it will just be (2009) i need to pull. Sometimes it will be (08-12).  But in some of the columns, there is text followed by a parenthesis with a comment, and then more text, and then the parenthesis with the year information. I need to skip the first parenthesis since there is not comment, and only extract the year information from the () with numbers in it.

Comment: unclear.....do **all** the characters in parenthesis need to be numerals or only the **first** character ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent No, all of the parentesis actually have look like this (12-16), and I need to extract "12-16".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use macro function for this. This macro returns the number inside the paranthesis and it assumes that if there is only one "-" character between numbers, it is a number. To remove this assumption change the `If (IsNumeric(Replace(result, "-", "", 1, 1, vbTextCompare))) Then` to `If (IsNumeric(result)) Then`.

assume that your excel file name is `Book1` and your `random Text Here (comment) more text (9999)` is located at cell A1

1. press ALT+F11. This will open the code editor
2. Right click on the `VBAProject(Book1)` and select `Insert`->`Module`
3. Copy and paste this macro inside the blank `Module1`

```
Function NumberInside(rng As Range, Optional startDelimiter As String = "(", Optional endDelimiter As String = ")")

    Dim txt As String, result As String, finalresult As String

    Dim startIndex As Integer, endIndex As Integer
    startIndex = 1
    txt = rng.Value
    result = ""
    finalresult = result
    Do Until startIndex = 0
        startIndex = InStr(startIndex, txt, startDelimiter, vbTextCompare)
        If (startIndex > 0) Then endIndex = InStr(startIndex + 1, txt, endDelimiter, vbTextCompare) Else Exit Do

        result = Mid(txt, startIndex + 1, endIndex - startIndex - 1)

        If (IsNumeric(Replace(result, "-", "", 1, 1, vbTextCompare))) Then
            finalresult = result
            Exit Do
        End If

        startIndex = startIndex + 1
    Loop

    NumberInside = finalresult

End Function
```

4.Now you can use the macro in your excel cell. Write `NumberInside(A1)` into cell `B1`

5.[optional] if you need to use angle parenthesis instead, you can write `NumberInside(A1;"<";">")`

[image: Sample data results]

Comment: I have put this in and having just a few problems on a few of my lines. Here is one line - TEXT (text), more text here (14-20) text (another comment in here).  And in this situation it is pulling the text "another comment in here" as opposed to the 14-20 i need. Could you help me understand the code a bit so I can change it to fix these few weird lines?  Thanks again so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

We need to find a special **(**.  That is **(** followed by a numeral.  We can use:

```
=MIN(FIND({"(1","(2","(3","(4","(5","(6","(7","(8","(9","(0"},A1 & "(1(2(3(4(5(6(7(8(9(0"))
```

[image]

So our extraction formula is:

```
=MID(A1,B1+1,FIND(")",A1,B1)-B1-1)
```

[image]

*(you can avoid the "helper" cell by replacing each of the three **B1**s with the first formula.)*

```
=MID(A1,MIN(FIND({"(1","(2","(3","(4","(5","(6","(7","(8","(9","(0"},A1 & "(1(2(3(4(5(6(7(8(9(0"))+1,FIND(")",A1,MIN(FIND({"(1","(2","(3","(4","(5","(6","(7","(8","(9","(0"},A1 & "(1(2(3(4(5(6(7(8(9(0")))-MIN(FIND({"(1","(2","(3","(4","(5","(6","(7","(8","(9","(0"},A1 & "(1(2(3(4(5(6(7(8(9(0"))-1)
```

But this is just plain ugly.